Does the Sono cancel noise from outside by vibrating a window?
Created by industrial designer Rudolf Stefanich, the Sono sticks to glass surfaces and claims to dial down unwanted noise. After it receives a sound’s vibrations, it claims to reprocess them much like the active noise cancellation technology used in certain headphones.
Sono’s interface claims to act as a dial, letting you choose which sounds you want blocked.
There's a slick video from 2013 with over 1 million views claiming to show its use.
Are these claims true?

Does the Sono act like noise cancelling headphones?
Can it block only certain sounds?


Welcome to Skeptics. We take questions about claims like "does the Sono actually cancel noise, and can it be dialed to block certain sounds?" We're not a pseudoscience shopping site.

I've reworded your question so it fits the site. You will have to provide 1) links to their claims and 2) evidence that the claim is "noteworthy". I'm personally good with it just being a product someone made and is marketing.

There was a product called Muzo which made similar claims and did not work.

Not well enough to make it to market
I can find no evidence it could do what it claimed, nor that it ever actually existed. What is certain is the inventor was convincing enough to a panel of judges to be a finalist for a James Dyson award in 2013.
However, the award does not require a working prototype. While articles claim there was a prototype, and there's a slick video demonstrating its (potential?) use, I could not find anyone who said they actually used one. It does not appear to be for sale.
A 2013 ExtremeTech article explains:

As you may have guessed, Sono does sound too good to be true within the realm of modern day technology, and it isn't a product you can go out and purchase at the moment. Rather, it's a concept created by Austrian industrial designer Rudolf Stefanich.

Prototypes fail to get to market all the time. It could have been too expensive, or not worked very well, or only with a very specific set of noises, etc.
According to an article interviewing the inventor...

Stefanich is currently looking for a partner and funding to complete the engineering for the device and usher it toward commercial production.

The basic idea appears to be sound
A university produced a similar effect in 2018, but with open windows.

Researchers from the School of Electrical and Electronic Engineering (NTU EEE) at Nanyang Technological University, Singapore have developed a device that can reduce noise pollution entering buildings through open windows.
Designed to be mounted onto window grilles, the device could reduce up to 50 per cent of noise coming from nearby environments such as busy roads, train tracks or from construction activities.
The device uses ‘active noise control’ technology – found in many high-end headphones that cancels external noise – and adapted to work in a large open area.

However, it was not a practical device.

Currently at the prototype stage, the device uses 8 watts of power, similar to a small portable Bluetooth speaker. Several units are placed together to form a grid-like array on a window grille to reduce external noise.
The device uses a special sound emitting mechanism which works like a speaker and is hooked up to a processing unit. Equipped with a microphone, it can detect noise even before it reaches the window and computes the attributes of the incoming noise in real-time.

The inventor's other claims...
The inventor made some additional claims about their device...

The major advance comes from the digital sound processing technology that "allows for more complex functions like selective noise cancelling or sound event detection," he explained. "For example, you could detect the sound of your neighbor's dog barking, cancel out that specific sound and replace it with with a bird's tweet."


The gadget's battery can be recharged the old-fashioned way via plugging it in to the grid, but it gets extra battery power by harvesting energy from the electromagnetic noise in the surrounding environment, such as Wi-Fi signals. That technology, Stefanich noted, is currently being developed at Nokia Research Center and may soon be a standard feature in many electronic gadgets.

That was in 2013 and, as far as I'm aware 11 years later, neither are features of home electronics.

Love the "it can detect noise even before it reaches the window".

Could the reason that it didn't make it to market be the cost of the product versus how much people would pay for it instead of how well it worked?

@JoeW Yes, for any product there will be a direct relationship between quality and price; higher quality, higher price. While demand has an inverse relationship with price; higher price, lower demand. But also higher quality, higher demand. Quantity also lowers price. So products have to offer acceptable quality at an acceptable price which produces sufficient demand to cover toolong up costs and make a profit.

This is physically a VERY difficult problem to solve (because of the 3D nature of the sound field). Note that even the Singaporean solution reduced noise "up to 50%". That turns out to be only 3dB of attenuation which is barely noticeable. Active noise cancelling headsets remove 99%+ of the noise energy and they only work  because the microphone, ear and cancelling loudspeaker are extremely close together.
